# Enabling XML under PHP in windows - import_html module not working

Tags: drush

So I'm having a problem with import_html. Basically, when I run the import from the sight, all of the content I wanted (except for xml files) get imported but I get these errors and warnings repeatedly:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 7 and head in Entity, line: 9 in parse_in_xml_string() (line 159 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\coders_php_library\xml-transform.inc).

User warning: Failed to cleanup namespaces and end up with a valid XML file in import_html_cleanup_namespaces() (line 1693 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\import_html_process.inc).

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in import_html_process_html_page() (line 875 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\import_html_process.inc).

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in xmldoc_plus_xsldoc() (line 211 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\coders_php_library\xml-transform.inc).

User warning: Nothing useful extracted via XML from that content in import_html_process_html_page() (line 903 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\import_html_process.inc).

Notice: Undefined variable: tid in import_html_indexes_import_html() (line 27 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\extras\import_html_indexes\import_html_indexes.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$title in node_import_html() (line 81 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\modules\core.inc).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$import_html_create_menus in menu_import_html_after_save() (line 159 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\modules\core.inc).

Deprecated function: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in charset_decode_utf_8() (line 2051 of 
C:\Bitnami\drupal\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules\import_html\import_html_process.inc).
```

When I run drush import-html,**nothing** gets imported and I get:

```
import_html found no XSL library support at all on this server! Need   [warning]
the PHP 'xsl' extension enabled in php.ini xml-transform.inc:31
Sorry, with no XML support there will be no content scanning AT ALL.     [error]
Aborting process. See the import_html_help.htm for info on enabling
XML under PHP. import_html_process.inc:724
WD Import HTML: Failed to process any node out of file                   [error]
'8ab24e480a68476f800648582eaabf43.html'
WD Import HTML:                                                          [error]
Failed to get any results from the attempted analysis of
8ab24e480a68476f800648582eaabf43.html.
The source file path was probably unavailable or not HTML.
WD Import HTML: No results! Failed to extract any new nodes            [warning]
Processing 1 files for import. Using default configuration settings.    [status]
```

Because I have a windows computer, I followed [these](http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php) directions for enabling xsl in php, and when I did so, I was able to get regular html files imported via the website import-html. But why am I getting these other errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why drush was giving me the XSL library support error is because though I fixed the php.ini file in the drupal folder, drush uses a different php.ini file, so I had to modify that one in order to get the imports to work. Now, I get the exact same errors/warning when I import online as when I import via drush. i haven't been able to fix the warnings

Comment: though i still haven't been able to fix the warnings...